# React Native iPhone simulator looks pixelated

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, react-native

I upgraded my XCode just now to 7.x from 6.x, and my simulator looks really pixelated and has poor anti-aliasing.

I used to leave the scale at 0.5, which looks fine, but that now takes up way too much space. When I lower it to 0.33, it looks bad:

[image]

You can see the font isn't smooth, the way it should be. It looks worse when you get into my app.

What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to turn off "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" in the Debug menu.  Performance will be worse, but the quality should return to what you are used to.

Comment: Doesn't work. It sounds like it *should* but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Use iPhone 6 Simulator instead of 6 Plus.

Comment: Strangely, this works... who knew? Obviously this fix won't work if you really *need* the 6 Plus and not the 6. Also it only works on 50% zoom or above.